# Run bash command that affect the parent shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash script that is suppose to activate a virtualenv in the current directory, `cd` into another folder and execute a command, i.e. export a pythonpath and print the pythonpath variable. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source venv/bin/activate
(cd cool/subcool && export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH)
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

When I execute it I just get a blanc line, i.e. the `$PYTHONPATH` is empty and no virtualenv is activated. I am  new to bash scripting. What would be the way to make this work? thanks

Comment: You're creating a subshell (with `(…)`). Variables set in it won't be seen outside of it.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=$(cd cool/subcool ; pwd):$PYTHONPATH`, but honestly, this is simpler: `PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/cool/subcool:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: yeah myaut answer is simple....just export the variable into the parent shell

Comment: What about the virtualenv? why is not activated?

Comment: It is.  But then the shell it was activated in terminates.  Bang, gone.

Comment: You are witnessing the exact reason you need to *source* `venv/bin/activate` in the current shell, rather than executing it as a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
source venv/bin/activate
PYTHONPATH=$(cd cool/subcool && echo $(pwd):$PYTHONPATH)
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

But you should name this file `foo.rc` or similar and then `source` it instead of call it (using `source` or `.` which is the same):

```
source foo.rc
```

Otherwise it does not influence your calling shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. Could I add more PATH to the PYTHONPATH variable following the same logic? and what's the difference between .sh and .rc?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the $PATH variable in any way you like.  Be careful not to remove parts accidentally, though.  `.sh` and `.rc` are just naming conventions.  `.sh` files are supposed to get executed, `.rc` files are supposed to get sourced.

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` seems overkill for adding a path to a variable. Why not use `readlink -f`?

```
source venv/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH="$(readlink -f cool/subcool):$PYTHONPATH"
echo "$PYTHONPATH"
```

Comment: I typically use `(cd some/dir; pwd -P)` for several reasons: It tests whether I can access that some/dir and canonizes the path (replaces all symlinks).  But without the `-P` option it seems out of place, yes.